# How to suppress JavaScript function with eg. hasClass?

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress

I'm building on a WordPress theme and wants to load posts and pages with AJAX. I got that sorted out through the snippet below, but now I just need to suppress the function when clicking on the logo, obviously linking to the home url. So when clicking on the logo it should force a normal reload, instead of using the function.

I figure it would have something to do with "if hasClass(logo) then use default"... Yeah, I'm fairly new to JavaScript, but I have been searching a lot, so any help in the right direction will be much appreciated. Thanks!

The snippet:

```
    $(".home li.home").removeClass("home").addClass("current_page_item");

    var $wrapperAjax = $("#wrapper-ajax"),
        URL = '',
        siteURL = "http://" + top.location.host.toString(),
        $internalLinks = $("a[href^='"+siteURL+"']"),
        hash = window.location.hash,
        $ajaxSpinner = $("#ajax-loader"),
        $el, $allLinks = $("a");

    function hashizeLinks() {
        $("a[href^='"+siteURL+"']").each(function() {
            $el = $(this);

            if ($.browser.msie) {
                $el.attr("href", "#/" + this.pathname)
                .attr("rel", "internal");
            } else {
                $el.attr("href", "#" + this.pathname)
                 .attr("rel", "internal");
            }
        });
    };

    hashizeLinks();  

    $("a[rel='internal']").live("click", function() {
        $ajaxSpinner.fadeIn();
        $wrapperAjax.animate({ opacity: "0.1" });
        $el = $(this);
        $(".current_page_item").removeClass("current_page_item");
        $allLinks.removeClass("current_link");
        URL = $el.attr("href").substring(1);
        URL = URL + " .entry";
        $wrapperAjax.load(URL, function() {
            $el.addClass("current_link").parent().addClass("current_page_item");
            $ajaxSpinner.fadeOut();
            $wrapperAjax.animate({ opacity: "1" });
            hashizeLinks();   
        });
    });

    $("#searchform").submit(function(e) {
        $ajaxSpinner.fadeIn();
        $wrapperAjax.animate({ opacity: "0.1" });
        $el = $(this);
        $(".current_page_item").removeClass("current_page_item");
        $allLinks.removeClass("current_link");
        URL = "/?s=" + $("#s").val() + " .entry";
        $wrapperAjax.load(URL, function() {
            $ajaxSpinner.fadeOut();
            $wrapperAjax.animate({ opacity: "1" });
            hashizeLinks();   
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    if ((hash) && (hash != "#/")) {
        $("a[href*='"+hash+"']").trigger("click");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If it has the class `.logo` you could add this at the top of the function:

```
if ($(this).hasClass('logo')) return true;
```

See the [simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/c2vVD/).

Comment: Thank you for a fast answer!
I have tried that, but without luck. Sorry

Comment: Are you sure you added it right at the start of the function?

Comment: I see your example, and thanks, but if I insert the line you posted, nothing happens... should I wrap it somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you mean the script from this line: `$("a[rel='internal']")`

In that case, `$("a[rel='internal']").not('.logo')` should do the trick.

I should've read the entire code. Replace `$("a[href^='"+siteURL+"']")` with `$("a[href^='"+siteURL+"']").not('.logo')` as well.

Comment: Thanks for a fast reply!
I have tried that, but it doesn't seem to work. When clicked links don't do anything.